# Remember Me Function At Login

Tags: android

I have two textbox and a checkmebox. But when i type my username and password and tick on the checkmebox, exit the application and go back again it doesn't appear. Why?

```
// Get reference to UI elements
        txtLogin = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtLogin);
        txtPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtPassword);

        SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,MODE_PRIVATE);   
        String username = pref.getString(PREF_USERNAME, null);
        String password = pref.getString(PREF_PASSWORD, null);

        if (username == null || password == null) {
            //Prompt for username and password
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                    "HI",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }


        // Remember me function
        CheckBox cbRemember = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chkRememberPassword);
        if (cbRemember.isChecked()) {

            getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,MODE_PRIVATE)
            .edit()
            .putString(PREF_USERNAME, txtLogin.toString())
            .putString(PREF_PASSWORD, txtPassword.toString())
            .commit();
        }
```

Comment: Is the code you posted from your onCreate or some other method within your `Activity`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: You should not be using `txtLogin.toString();` but rather use `txtLogin.getText();` to get the values from the editText controls.

Are you sure the code that saves the preferences is invoked?

Answer (score 0):

use these to get value

```
   String username = txtLogin.getText().toString().trim();
```